# Who is the 'Companion' in ayat 50:23 and 50:27?

Tags: tafseer, jahannam

I'm working with the Abdullah Yusuf Ali translation.

- [50:23](https://quran.com/50/23?translations=22). And his Companion will say: "Here is (his Record) ready with me!"
- [50:27](https://quran.com/50/23?translations=22). His Companion will say: "Our Lord! I did not make him transgress, but he was (himself) far astray."
- What is this Surah about in general?

Answer (score 2):

As for the first verse, the companion refers to an angel, particularly the one recording bad deeds.

As for the second verse, it is possible it refers to the same angel, but the more correct and majority opinion is that it refers to the devil that tried to misguide him in the world.

Answer (score 2):

This Surah is about disbelievers wonder at the Message(Islam) and Resurrection(Day of Judgement). We can refer back to [Tafsir ibn Kathir](http://m.qtafsir.com) for explanation.

**(50:23):** The scribe angel, who is entrusted with recording the deeds of mankind, will testify against him or her about the deeds he or she did on the Day of Resurrection.

**(50:27):** Man and Devil dispute before Allah. (His companion will say), refers to the devil who is entrusted to every man. He will say, (Our Lord! I did not push him to transgression,) meaning, the devil will say this about the human who came on the Day of Resurrection as a disbeliever. The devil will disown him, saying, (Our Lord! I did not push him to transgression) meaning, "I did not lead him astray," (but he was himself in error far astray.) meaning, he himself was misguided, accepting falsehood and stubborn to the truth.